A subset of the set of vertices of a simple graph with an even/odd property
Let $G$ be a simple graph, and let $V$ be its set of vertices. Consider the following statement:

There is a subset $S$ of $V$ such that, for each $v\in S$, there is an even number of elements of $S$ for which there is an edge joining it to $v$ and that, for each $v\in V\setminus S$, there is an odd number of elements of $S$ for which there is an edge joining it to $v$.

For instance:

If $G$ has no edges, one can simply take $S=V$.
If there is some vertex $v\in V$ such that, for each $w\in V\setminus\{v\}$, there is an edge joining $v$ to $w$, one can take $S=\{v\}$.

I know how to prove this, but my guess is that there is some graph-theoretical theorem of which the statement is an easy corollary. Can anyone find such a theorem or some graph-theoretical approach to the problem? The way of proving it that I am aware of uses Linear Algebra and I want to know some other approach which, if possible, is more in the spirit of Graph Theory.
